# Symfony Exception : value required for $request argument

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

i have a loginAction that looks something like this:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request){
    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        $mail = $request->getContent('umail');
        $pass = $request->getContent('upass');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $rep = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:User');

        $user = $rep->findOneBy(array("email"=>$mail,"pass"=>$pass));
        if($user){
            $id = $user->getId();
            $type = $user->getType();

            return $this->render('@System/Pages/admin/index.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

after submitting the form I am getting following error:

> Controller "SystemBundle\Controller\SystemController::loginAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$request" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

following is the routing:

```
system_login:
path: /login
defaults: { _controller: SystemBundle:System:login}
```

and the form:

```
<form method="POST" id="lgn" action="{{ path('system_login') }}">
        <span class="fa fa-times close" onclick="lgn()" ></span><br />
        <span>Login:</span>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" name="umail" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" name="upass" />
        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
```

Please help...

Comment: Did you correctly import `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` class ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credit to Kuba Birecki for his comment with this answer.

Symfony is failing to autowire the $request argument because it doesn't match it's list of available autowire-able argument types. This is likely because when you added the Request typehint, your IDE added a `use` statement for the wrong class.

Make sure the `use` statement is for `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`.

Answer (score 4):

I think problem in your **Controller**. Try this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class FooController extends Controller
{

    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {

       if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
       {
          $mail = $request->request->get('umail');
          $pass = $request->request->get('upass');
          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $rep = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:User');

          $user = $rep->findOneBy(array("email"=>$mail,"pass"=>$pass));
          if($user)
          {
             $id = $user->getId();
             $type = $user->getType();

             return $this->render('@System/Pages/admin/index.html.twig');
          }
      }
   }
```

}